# Selecionar un checkbox en una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html5, laravel-5

hoy me planteo el siguiente problema, tengo en la vista de mi pagina web una tabla con clientes que jalo de la base de datos hasta  ahí todo bien, a la par de los clientes tengo un select de checkbox para que cuando yo quiera subir un archivo pueda seleccionar varios usuarios a los que le voy a enviar ese archivo, pero al recorrer y hacer una prueba solo me tira el primero de la lista cuando selecciono cualquier checkbox de la tabla, o selecciono varios, 
en la siguiente les paso el html de la vista.

```
<div class="scroll_vertical">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll" >

        <tbody id="dtDynamicVerticalScroll">
            <tr>
                <th ></th>
                <th ></th> 
            @foreach($clients as $client)
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  onclick="return golbat()" name="checkit"  id="cheid"></td>
                <td id="clientetd">{{@client}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

en la siguiente la función que use para ver que sale solo uno de la lista pero quiero selecciona todos los posibles o solo uno de cualquier posición en la tabla y enviarle los archivos.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function golbat(){
        var take = document.getElementById("clientetd").innerHTML;
        swal("click"+ take);
    }  
</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#dtDynamicVerticalScroll').DataTable({
           "scrollY": "50vh",
           "scrollCollapse": true,
       });
       $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
   });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    div.scroll_vertical {
        height: 280px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 0px solid #666;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 2px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el [selector de clase](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), como el ejemplo que pongo a continuación ya que veo que estas utilizando JQuery en este caso aunque no exista las clases group1 y group2, pero me permiten agrupar e identificar a los checkboxes que han sido **checked** con input:checkbox:checked.group1, sin necesidad de un id para cada uno como en el ejemplo que muestro a continuación, en donde me regresa un arreglo de los valores de los checkboxes que han sido **checked**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejemplo de selector checkboxes</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
         var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.group1').map(function () {
       return this.value;
     }).get();
         console.log( "valores:" +values);
     });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="18" checked="checked" />18 group1 seleccionado<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="20" />20 group1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="15" />15 group1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group2" value="14" />14 group1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="55" checked="checked" />55 group1 seleccionado<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="10" checked="checked" />10 group1 seleccionado<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group2" value="77" checked="checked" />77 <b>group2</b> seleccionado<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="11" />11 group1<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: funciona correctamente,  muchas gracias.

Comment: hola, una consulta, el funciona bien pero solo me obtiene el primero de la fila  y ocupo que me tome cualquiera que seleccione, sin importar la posición como se haría

Comment: @RojasRodriguezRicardo todos los checkbox tienen el atributo class

Comment: si es que esta siendo recorrido por un foreach que me tarea la información y pone el id del cliente por así decirlo  en  el checkbox

Comment: pero si todas los checkbox tienen la misma class

Answer (score 0):

En vez de un id, puedes utilizar una clase

```
<td class = "claseTD"></td>
```

y para hacer el recorrido puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
    $('.claseTD').each(function(){
       var actual = $(this);
       //hacer lo demas que quieras
     })
```

Comment: al recargar la pagina para probar  me tira el evento inmediato,  cuando cargo la pagina y me sale como un tdElementOutput en ves de que sea el cliente,